# Validate if particular value exists then In other column should not be null

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two columns, If `pricesource` column has a value like 'Prior Value' and `PO_DATE` column has Nulls, Then i have to display the message "It has Nulls", I have tried something like this, but not getting proper output. Correct me

```
Dim rst As Recordset
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("select pricesource from [Input Norm] where pricesource='Prior File'")
If rst And IsNull(PO_DATE) Then
MsgBox "PO_DATE HAS NULLS, Please check"
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Dim rst As Recordset

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("select PO_DATE from [Input Norm] where pricesource='Prior File'")
If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
    If IsNull(rst!PO_DATE.Value) Then
        MsgBox "PO_DATE has Nulls, please check."
    End If
End If
rst.Close

Set rst = Nothing
```